# Product details page image zoom issue - Magento 2

Tags: product, magento-2.1, php, zoom

In product page the **Zoomed Image** will display when I click on the product image. If I click the **Close Icon** on zoom it displays a blank page sometimes.
I expect the zoom window should close. I don't know why it is coming like this.

I think this problem coming in default theme also.

Kindly help me out.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Unfortunately no errors.

Comment: hi @murali raj could you post/update the screenshots for better understanding

Comment: @Murali Raj have you got any solution for this ? i have also the same issue.

Comment: @amesh No buddy!! Still I didn't get any solution.